# GitLab API: Access snippets without project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-8

Using the [GitLab API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html) (version 8.x) it is possible to access **project snippets** via `GET /projects/:id/snippets` (see [project snippets](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/project_snippets.html) docs).

The Python request for snippet `4` of the project `pr` in the group `gr` would look like (with `2%F` = `/`):

```
r = requests.get(url='https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/projects/gr2%Fpr/snippets/4')
```

But I can't figure out a way to access a snippet, which is **not associated with any project**, something like https://gitlab.com/snippets/14383, although the web interface can create and display those snippets. Is there a way to do that via the API?

**Further information:**
I have a public snipped on a self hosted GitLab server, which leads to a `500 Server Error` somehow and I want to delete this snippet via the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm (Feb. 2016) this API does not seem to exist at the moment (in the [GitLab API doc](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/)).

There was an old 2013 suggestion for [public snippet API in 2013](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-deprecated-feedback-forum/suggestions/5157412-api-for-creating-public-private-snippets), but that issue has not been reported in the current [GitLab.org/GitLab Community Edition project](https://gitlab.com/search?group_id=&project_id=13083&scope=issues&search=snippet).

So... PR are welcome.

---

Update June 2016:

The [OP bastelflp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5276734/bastelflp) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139812/gitlab-api-access-snippets-without-project/35153328?noredirect=1#comment63679386_35153328):

> In the meantime GitLab was updated some times.
>   **With the current version 8.8.5, the snippets did not cause a 500 error anymore and could be deleted via the web interface**.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation of my problem, so it is a thing. Do you have any idea how to delete a snipped which causes a `500` from the web interface?

Comment: @bastelflp I do not know that. 500 means exception at the server level. What do the GitLab logs show?

Comment: The log is here: http://pastebin.com/LCykQ8y2 and it shows `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method \`path_with_namespace' for nil:NilClass):` and I used `path_with_namespace` somewhere in the snipped (it was a markdown `snippet.md`). So it seems to be a parsing error for my content.

Comment: In the meantime GitLab was updated some times and with the current version `8.8.5` the snippets did not cause a `500` error anymore and could be deleted via the web interface.

Comment: @bastelflp Sounds great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.